# Cannonical Correspondence Analysis (CCA) using R

Tags: r, vegan

I use R for my data analysis, and I found an error when I use vegan packages for calculating and plotting CCA (Canonical Correspondence Analysis). One of all variable was loose and the eigenvalues different.

These is eigenvalues when I use R

```
Eigenvalues for constrained axes:
   CCA1    CCA2    CCA3    CCA4    CCA5 
0.18496 0.02405 0.01492 0.01103 0.00260
```

And this is eigenvalues when I use PAST

```
Axis    Eigenvalue  %
1   0.11343 74.19
2   0.023363    15.28
3   0.011034    7.217
4   0.0050609   3.31
5   1.2233E-10  8.002E-08
```

I don't know about my fault. I need some problem solving

Comment: Would help if you added code and data enough to make your problem reproducible

Comment: There seems to be no PAST tag in StackOverflow, but they have a mailing list at PAST <past-users@nhm.uio.no>. However, my guess is that you have defined your models differently in PAST and in vegan. We need something to reproduce, though.

Comment: this is my code > library(readxl)
> abiotik <- read_excel("D:/study/R-/Jurnal Pak Nia/abiotik.xlsx")
> library("vegan", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
> abiotic <- abiotik [,c ('Temperature', 'Relative_Humidity', 'Rainfall', 'Water Conductivity', 'Water Temperature', 'Water pH')]
> species <- abiotik [,c ('Culicidae', 'pyralidae', 'Formicidae', 'Delphacidae', 'Chrysomelidae', 'Poecilia_sp.', 'Lymnea_truncatula', 'M._granifera', 'M._plicaria', 'M._tuberculata')]
> modelcca <- cca(species, abiotic)
> plot(modelcca) @JariOksanen Richard Telford

Comment: We stil cannot reproduce the problem, because we do not have the data. Moreover, the problem was the difference between vegan and PAST. I haven't used PAST, and cannot help there. However, I do think that you did something different in PAST. For PAST problems you should contact the PAST email list (I subscribe to that list and I haven't seen your message there yet).

Comment: okay, i will give you the data.